# Is it possible to get window instance somehome in the javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, webrtc

I am tring to write stand alone node.js application, in which i would like to get the browser API .

Example:

```
window.RTCSessionDescription
```

Is it possible to get like this?

Comment: Why you need browse api in node application ?

Comment: @CodeBean, i would like to create peer connection to using WebRTC API in the non browser application.

Comment: I am not sure https://developers.google.com/talk/libjingle/libjingle_applications matches.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a browser API in Node, like if your code was running in a browser, then you can use modules like:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-dom
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-dom
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodejs-dom
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/dom-layer

If you want to access the actual `window` object of the browser that is doing the request that your Node application is serving, then you won't be able to access it directly. You would have to serve some JavaScript to the browser that would access the browser's API on your behalf and communicate with your Node application via HTTP, WebSocket or in some other way.